# php mail function not sending email when From address is yahoo

Tags: php, email, sendmail, yahoo

Not sure if anyone else has experienced this but i have a simple form that sends out a email.

```
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" />
      <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message"></textarea>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
 </form>
```

When submitted i have the following:

```
 if ($_POST) {
     $email_to = "myemail@yahoo.com";
     $subject = "Contact Form"; 
     $message = "Phone: {$phone}\r\nMessage: {$msg}";
     $headers = "From: sendingemail@yahoo.com" . "\r\n";
     mail($email_to,$subject,$message, $headers);

 }
```

When the form is submitted the mail function returns true but no email gets sent however when i change the FROM email to anything else outside of yahoo such as something@gmail.com the email comes through. Anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Yahoo blocked you. Google wants your business. Get PHPmailer or Swiftmailer.

Comment: Definitely a server side problem.

Comment: did you check your SPAM box at Yahoo?

Comment: I figured it would be a server problem but i called the hosting company and they said its a problem with my form? doesnt make sense

Comment: @Yeak - if the form works with a non-Yahoo email, but fails with a Yahoo email address, then the form is clearly working. Most likely Yahoo are classing your emails as spam, and either routing them into people's spam folders, or just silently deleting them. There are fixes, but you need to do things like set up SPF records for your domain.

Comment: Just use SMTP from a real account?

Comment: Thanks guys wanted to make sure it wasn't code related. Gonna close this issue thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo marked your mail as spam and is probably just ignoring it.
This is probably true for hotmail as well.

Best thing todo is find yourself a good SMTP mail pluging/module (phpMailer for instance) and use the credentials of a legit mail account. This way you are sending mail trough a dedicated mail server and changes are you won't be marked as spam anymore.

Do notice however than when you sent loads of (simular) mails or your script gets hacked and is used for spamming, changes are that your legit mailserver becomes blacklisted or (if you are lucky) blocks your account as beeing unsafe.